# Using The Exit Sub Statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code where I'm basically looping through and copying data from one excel sheet and pasting it into my active workbook. However, the current way I have my code written I'm using the `Exit Sub` statement and everything below that statement will not execute. Is there an alternative I can use to the `Exit Sub` which will still work with my current code structure?

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim Prefix As String, Suffix As String
Dim ROfs As Integer, COfs As Integer
Dim Source As Range, Dest As Range, This As Range


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")



  With ws
    'The formula becomes Prefix & Source.Address & Suffix
    Prefix = "='C:x\xx\[Workbook1.xls]Worksheet1'!"
    Suffix = "/1000"
    'Direction for the next Source cell
    COfs = -1

    'Destination cells
    Set Dest = .Range("G8:G12")
    Set Source = Range("G8")
    GoSub Fill

    Set Dest = .Range("G13:G17")
    Set Source = Range("G9")
    GoSub Fill
    
    Suffix = ""
    Set Dest = .Range("G3:G7")
    Set Source = Range("G10")
    GoSub Fill

    Suffix = "/1000"
    Set Dest = .Range("G26:G30")
    Set Source = Range("G35")
    GoSub Fill
   
    Suffix = ""
    Set Dest = .Range("G21:G25")
    Set Source = Range("G37")
    GoSub Fill
   
    Suffix = "/1000"
    Set Dest = .Range("G31:G35")
    Set Source = Range("G36")
    GoSub Fill
    
  End With
  
Exit Sub
 
Fill:
  For Each This In Dest
    This.Formula = Prefix & Source.Address(0, 0) & Suffix
    Set Source = Source.Offset(ROfs, COfs)
  Next
  Dest.Value = Dest.Value
  Return

'''Everything Below Does Not Execute'''

ws.Columns("C").EntireColumn.Delete

Dim strFormulas As Variant

    With ws
         strFormulas = "=(F3-C3)"
        .Range("G3:G17").Formula = strFormulas
        .Range("G3:G17").FillDown
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What does this line do: `Dest.Value = Dest.Value`?

Comment: I use that to get rid of the cell reference. It's essentially the same as Paste as Values

Comment: I would make Fill:  block a separate sub that takes args. It will make your code a lot easier to read. You could likely then remove your Exit Sub.

Comment: `GoSub` is a hangover from a much earlier era of Basic.  Don't use it. Ever.

Comment: Thanks for the info Chris, I had no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `Gosub/Return` - as noted in the comments, that's not an "idiomatic" way to write in VBA

```vb
Sub Test()
    
    Dim prefix As String, suffix As String
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        'The formula becomes Prefix & Source.Address & Suffix
        prefix = "='C:x\xx\[Workbook1.xls]Worksheet1'!"
        suffix = "/1000"
        
        'Destination cells
        DoFill Range("G8"), .Range("G8:G12"), prefix, suffix
        DoFill Range("G9"), .Range("G13:G17"), prefix, suffix
        DoFill Range("G10"), .Range("G3:G7"), prefix, ""
        DoFill Range("G35"), .Range("G26:G30"), prefix, suffix
        DoFill Range("G37"), .Range("G21:G25"), prefix, ""
        DoFill Range("G36"), .Range("G31:G35"), prefix, suffix
    
        .Columns("C").EntireColumn.Delete
        .Range("G3:G17").Formula = "=(F3-C3)"
    End With
      
End Sub

Sub DoFill(src As Range, dest As Range, prefix As String, suffix As String)
      Dim c As Range
      For Each c In dest
        c.Formula = prefix & src.Address(0, 0) & suffix
        Set src = src.Offset(0, -1)
      Next
      dest.Value = dest.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. This makes a lot more sense than what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle the last code blocks:

```vb
' <snip>

  End With
  
ws.Columns("C").EntireColumn.Delete

Dim strFormulas As Variant

    With ws
         strFormulas = "=(F3-C3)"
        .Range("G3:G17").Formula = strFormulas
        .Range("G3:G17").FillDown
   End With

Exit Sub
 

Fill:
  For Each This In Dest
    This.Formula = Prefix & Source.Address(0, 0) & Suffix
    Set Source = Source.Offset(ROfs, COfs)
  Next
  Dest.Value = Dest.Value
  Return

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use a "goto" for that, is better to call a function or sub.

The "goto" are perfect in vba for catch errors